# Add classes to the Winforms menustrip dropdown 'new item' menu

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, windows-forms-designer

I'm creating some custom classes that derive from ToolStripMenuItem.  I'd like my new classes to show up in the 'new item' dropdown menu on my menustrip.

Is there a specific step I must take to accomplish this?  I have the DLL's controls added to my toolbox, but I'm not sure what other steps I can take.

Its worth noting that some classes do show up.  They are all part of irrelevant dll's and not the controls im currently working with, or the wants I want to show up.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: Im writing a controls library for other people to use.  Among those custom controls is custom tool strip menu items. As you can see in the screencap above, it has some over the custom items I've developed.
However, it doesn't have them all, and in fact, I don't know how to modify that list.